# How to hide items when search field is cleared?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to hide items when the search field is cleared, but when i search for a item and clear the search field all items will be visible.

i've tried

```
 if(input.value.length == 0){
                a[i].style.display = "none";
                return;
            }else{
                a[i].style.display = "block";
            }
```

But this will give a error:

`index.php:160` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at filterFunction (`index.php:160`)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (`index.php:125`)

Line 125:    `<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">`

Line 160:   `filter = input.value.toUpperCase();`

This is the code:

```
      <div class="dropdown">
                            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." 
        id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
                                <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
                                <a href="">Refurbish Desktop</a>
                                <a href="">Refurbish Laptop</a>
                                <a href="">Refurbish Monitoren</a>
                                <a href="">Refurbish Printers</a>
                                <a href="">Groothandel Desktop</a>
                                <a href="">Groothandel Laptop</a>
                                <a href="">Groothandel Monitoren</a>
                                <a href="">Groothandel Printers</a>
                                <a href="">Recycling Desktop</a>
                                <a href="">Recycling Laptop</a>
                                <a href="">Recycling Thin Client</a>
                                <a href="">Recycling Monitoren</a>
                                <a href="">Recycling Printers</a>
                                <a href="">Werkproces HP Folio 9470m</a>
                                <a href="">QA Refurbish Desktop</a>
                                <a href="">QA Refurbish Laptop</a>
                                <a href="">QA Refurbish Monitoren</a>
                                <a href="">QA Refurbish Printers</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

              <script>

                    function filterFunction() {
                      var input, filter, a, i;
                      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                      div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
                      a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
                      if(input.value.length == 0){
                        a[i].style.display = "none";
                        return;
                    }else{
                        a[i].style.display = "block";
                    }
                      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                        txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
                        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                          a[i].style.display = "block";
                        } else {
                          a[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    </script>
```

I would like to have the field to be cleared when the field is cleared

Comment: Hi @IstiaqueHossain to be honest i dont, this is the first time i work with a java (javascript)

Comment: https://www.thesoftwareguild.com/faq/difference-between-java-and-javascript/

Comment: Thank you, i will look into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not defined `i` for first time

Try this:

```
if(input.value.length == 0){
     for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
           a[i].style.display = "none";
     }
     return;
}
else{
     for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
           a[i].style.display = "block";
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi this works, thanks a lot, i thought i had already defined ```i```  
```for (i = 0; i < a.length; 
txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i]. if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) ```

Answer (score 0):

You using `onkeyup` event on input tag. Can you try `onkeydown`  instead of `onkeyup` ?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeydown="filterFunction()">
```

Comment: Hi @ariferol01 The comment above fixed my issue. but thanks anyway.